# LINQ NULL exceptions from SubList or property of a SubList

Tags: c#, linq

I am getting the NULL exception for the below LINQ query

```
   List<Subscription> product_subscriptions = (from i in _subscriptions
                                                    where i.SubscriptionLines.Any(l => 
                                                     l.ProductNo == isbn)
                                                    select i).ToList();
```

It looks like SubscriptionLines can be NULL in some cases and ProductNo [ from sublist] also can be null. Can we avoid this NULL exception in same query

Comment: Is this Linq-to-Entities or Linq-to-Objects or some other Linq backend?

Comment: It is LinqtoObjects

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "avoid `null`". if `SubscriptionLines ` is `null` do you want to get back such a subscription or not?

Comment: If SubscriptionLInes is NULL we can avoid them completely. No point of checking further

Answer (score 4):

- First off, I recommend avoiding the `from x in y where z` syntax because it makes queries harder to read. All the cool kids are using extension-methods exclusively now.
- Also, the term "`NULL`" (in all-caps) should only be used when discussing C or SQL. In C# it's "`null`" (and in C++ everyone should be using `nullptr` instead of the `NULL` macro, but that's another rant).
- This is your query using the extension-method syntax (see how much shorter it is?):

  ```
  List<Subscription> product_subscriptions = _subscriptions
      .Where( s => s.SubscriptionLines.Any( line => line.ProductNo == isbn ) )
      .ToList();
  ```
- Making it null-safe requires only adding an extra `.Where()` step:

  ```
  List<Subscription> product_subscriptions = _subscriptions
      .Where( s => s.SubscriptionLines != null )
      .Where( s => s.SubscriptionLines.Any( line => line.ProductNo == isbn ) )
      .ToList();
  ```

  - Note that it doesn't matter if `line.ProductNo` can be null because the `==` operator handles `null` values fine. If `line` itself can be null, then you can workaround that by changing the `Any` predicate to this: `line => line?.ProductNo == isbn`.

Comment: "I recommend avoiding the from x in y where z syntax because it makes queries harder to read" - it depends on a query actually, some of them look much better using query expression syntax rather than "dot" notation. I just would recommend to use clear names for range variables instead of `i, x, y, z`

Comment: @E.Shcherbo I fully understand your position and I do agree with you to an extent, but I must respectfully disagree for reasons I won't go into because it's 4am and I really shouldn't even be on StackOverflow at this time argh.

Comment: sure, both of us have some reasons to prefer one way over another one, but my opinion is that it's good to know about both ways of writing queries (and refactor them appropriately) and use either of them depending on situation, team conventions etc. But anyway, if you're still gonna go to bed, then good night :)

Comment: `.Where( s => s.SubscriptionLines != null && s.SubscriptionLines.Any( line => line.ProductNo == isbn )` would work as well, because of C#'s short circuit evaluation of logical expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Check whether `SubscriptionLines is` null` before accessing it. Eg :

```
var query=from s in _subscriptions
          where s.SubscritpionLines !=null 
                && s.SubscriptionLines.Any( line => line.ProductNo == isbn )
          select s;
var product_subscriptions=query.ToList();
```

You can also use the null-safe operator :

```
var query=from s in _subscriptions
          where s.SubscritpionLines
                 ?.Any( line => line.ProductNo == isbn ) ==true
          select s;
```

Which ends up a bit uglier. Using fluent syntax :

```
var product_subscriptions = _subscriptions
                              .Where(s=>s.SubscritpionLines !=null 
                                     && s.SubscriptionLines.Any( 
                                           line => line.ProductNo == isbn ))
                              .ToList();
```

Which is even uglier or :

```
var product_subscriptions = _subscriptions
                              .Where(s=>s.SubscritpionLines
                                        ?.Any( line => line.ProductNo == isbn ) ==true)
                              .ToList();
```

Comment: Is the last one going to be working? I think you want to compare it against `null` or `true`

Comment: @E.Shcherbo oops